# onSaveInstanceState gives me parcelable error...sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bundle, twitter4j

I have an ArrayList<> of [Status](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html) from the library Twitter4j.
This is my onSaveInstanceState method:

```
    @Override
     protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("TWEET_LIST", tweetList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

If I rotate the device, all works fine, but everytime I try to start another activity, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = twitter4j.StatusJSONImpl)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1388)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:711)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1284)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2884)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3261)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: twitter4j.ScopesImpl
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1383)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:711)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1284)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2884)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3261)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the stacktrace suggests that twitter4j.ScopesImpl is not serializable.
And, in fact, if you look at it's source, https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/internal-json/java/twitter4j/ScopesImpl.java you will see that indeed it is not.